# Unable to print QWidget to PDF at high resolution

Tags: python, pdf-generation, qwidget, pyside6, qprinter

I am trying to print a QWidget to pdf at A4 page size with QPrinter. But unable to generate it in a better quality. The PDF looks blurry. Please find the code I have tried below. Any help regarding the pdf quality is highly appreciable.

```
import os
import datetime
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize
from PySide6.QtGui import QPageSize
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QLabel, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView
from PySide6.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("")
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(794, 1123))
        self.line = QLineEdit()
        self.l1 = QLabel("This is testing")
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget(4,5, self)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Item", "Batch"])
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table_widget.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem("Batch no"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(0,2, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(0,3, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(1,2, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(1,3, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(2,0, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        self.table_widget.setItem(2,1, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name"))
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        

    def exportToPDF(self, filename):
        printer = QPrinter()
        printer.setPageSize(QPageSize.A4)
        printer.PrinterMode.HighResolution
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(filename)

        self.render(printer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    example = Example()
    example.show()
    example.exportToPDF("invoice_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')) + ".pdf")
    os.system("start " + "invoice_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')) + ".pdf")
    
    app.exec()
```

Please find the pdf attached here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p1HbfRQixZ-lfERtfzlF_ZPFX3pkT_tv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "acceptable quality" is an extremely vague concept. Please [edit] your post and clarify *in detail* what your issue is. If you have proper visual results of your code that clearly show the problem, then include them to the post, possibly by adding an example (including a mock-up) of the expected result.

Comment: Thank you @musicamante for your time. I have updated the post. Could you please recheck the post when you have some time.

Comment: Firstly, it's worth pointing out that QPrinter doesn't really convert the table into PDF format. All it does is create a screen-dump of the widget, then scales it according to the print parameters and splits it up into page-sized pieces. So the final PDF will just contain a series of images, rather than formatted text. Secondly, your code doesn't actually use high resolution. To do that, you need to do `printer = QPrinter( QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution)`. However, that may still not give the desired results, so you should also try experimenting with `setResolution()`.

Comment: @Sayan As suggested above, you should both try a different mode in the constructor and eventually do some tests with `setResolution()`. Note that the line `printer.PrinterMode.HighResolution` is completely pointless, and, in theory, you should also call `setPageSize()` with an instance of QPageSize, not one of its enums. Finally, posts should be self contained and not rely on external services (especially repositories or cloud services), otherwise the question may become invalid. Instead, take a screenshot that shows the issue in the pdf file, and add it to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I would first like to thank @musicamante, @ekhumoro and @KJ for your help. I finally figured out a solution. Here I am sharing the updated code.

```
import os
import datetime
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize
from PySide6.QtGui import QPageSize, QFont
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QLabel, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView
from PySide6.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(2480, 3508))
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget(35,5, self)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Item", "Batch", "MRP", "Quantity", "Amount"])
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setFont(QFont("Arial", 30))
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
        self.table_widget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
        self.table_widget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        self.table_widget.setFont(QFont("Arial", 30))
        for i in range(0,35):
            for j in range(0,5):
                self.table_widget.setItem(i,j, QTableWidgetItem("Item Name_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)))

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        

    def exportToPDF(self, filename):
        printer = QPrinter()
        pageSize = QPageSize(QPageSize.A4)
        printer.setPageSize(pageSize)
        printer.setResolution(300)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(filename)

        self.render(printer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    example = Example()
    example.show()
    example.exportToPDF("invoice_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')) + ".pdf")
    os.system("start " + "invoice_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')) + ".pdf")
    
    app.exec()
```